# Google Recaptcha Ajax response strange checking order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, registration, recaptcha

I am making my registration page for my service. I need to check either Google's Recaptcha successfully verified or not. I decided to use an jquery.ajax.

I have created a function "**checkCaptcha()**" which sets **isCAPT** (if captcha valid or not) either true (FLD_VALID) or not (FLD_EMPTY):

```
function checkCaptcha() {
                alert("1");
                var captcha_response_text = grecaptcha.getResponse();

                var request = $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax/registrationA.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: { captcha: true, captcha_response: captcha_response_text }
                });

                request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("2");
                    if(response) {
                        isCAPT = FLD_VALID;
                    }
                    else {
                        isCAPT = FLD_EMPTY;
                    }
                });
            }
```

I have to say that "**registrationA.php**" works fine. No problems there.

After this function, I am checking my submit button handling "onclick" event:

```
apply_button.onclick = function () {
                checkCaptcha();
                alert("3");
                //alert("Капча " + isCAPT + " Логин " + isLOGIN + " Почта " + isMAIL + " Пароль " + isPASS + " Соответствие " + isPAS2);
                return false;
            };
```

You can see three "**alert(...)**" operators. The problem is that when I press submit button (apply_button) I get three alerts: 1, 3, 2. How can I fix this problem. I need to wait until "requiest.done" executes and only than go to "**alert("3")**". It is essential because now this function checks fields **before** checking captcha state which leads to an error because in this case isCAPT equals **false**.

Please help me with this problem. Maybe there is a better way to check if captcha verified or not (maybe there is a function like "**grecaptcha.isVerified**").

Comment: You are working with asynchronous data, so there is no way to guarantee a response in a synchronous order. Perhaps you can move your `apply_button.onclick` function inside the `request.done` call back.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check **deferred.promise()** method to work with asynchronous data. Check [JQ documentation](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) for that. In a few words it does exactly what you need. It allows to wait until the 2nd asynchronous request is finished and starts the 3d function.